# Copy a single file to all sub directories under a certain directory using Ant Script

Tags: php, netbeans, ant

How can I make a script using Ant to copy a single file index.html to all sub-directories of a directory.

I'm trying to build an Ant script to copy index.html over all sub-directories. If the file exists in a specific sub-directory, the file should be replaced.

My initial structure:

```
Directory A
   Sub-Directory AA
       file1
       file2
       ...
   Sub-Directory AB
       file1
       file2
       index.html
       ...
      Sub-Directory ABA
          file1
          file2
          ...
    ....
```

I want to achieve this:

```
Directory A
   Sub-Directory AA
       file1
       file2
       index.html  <- file copied
       ...
   Sub-Directory AB
       file1
       file2
       index.html  <- file replaced
       ...
      Sub-Directory ABA
          file1
          file2
          index.html  <- file copied
          ...
    ....
```

Thanks in advance. Regards.

Comment: If they're all copies of the same file why not just use symlinks instead?

Comment: I have hundreds of directories and I want to make sure those directories have index.html file inside. I think symlink will not do that...

Answer (score 0):

The following example uses the [groovy](http://groovy.codehaus.org/The+groovy+Ant+Task) ANT task.

## Example

```
├── build.xml
├── lib
│   └── groovy-all-2.1.6.jar
├── src
│   └── index.html
└── target
    └── DirectoryA
        ├── index.html
        ├── SubdirectoryAA
        │   └── index.html
        └── SubdirectoryAB
            ├── index.html
            └── SubdirectoryABA
                └── index.html
```

### build.xml

```
<project name="demo" default="copy">

   <path id="build.path">
      <pathelement location="lib/groovy-all-2.1.6.jar"/>
   </path>

   <target name="copy">
      <taskdef name="groovy" classname="org.codehaus.groovy.ant.Groovy" classpathref="build.path"/>

      <dirset id="trgDirs" dir="target/DirectoryA"/>

      <groovy>
         project.references.trgDirs.each {
            ant.copy(file:"src/index.html", todir:it, overwrite:true, verbose:true)
         }
      </groovy>
   </target>

</project>
```

Notes:

- The groovy script is able to loop thru the directories contained in the ANT dirset.
- Groovy has access to the normal ANT tasks. Note the "overwrite" flag on the copy operation.